# using re.findall when in need of striping a string into words in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm using `re.findall` like this:

```
x=re.findall('\w+', text)
```

so I'm getting a list of words matching the characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.
the problem is when I'm using this input:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~:
```

I want to get an empty list, but im getting ['*', '*']. how could
I exclude those underscores?

Answer (score 3):

Use **just** the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` pattern; `\w` includes underscores:

```
x = re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9]+', text)
```

or use the inverse of `\w`, `\W` in a negative character set with `_` added:

```
x = re.findall('[^\W_]+', text)
```

The latter has the advantage of working correctly even when using `re.UNICODE` or `re.LOCALE`, where `\w` matches a wider range of characters.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~:'
>>> re.findall('[^\W_]+', text)
[]
>>> re.findall('[^\W_]+', 'The foo bar baz! And the eggs, ham and spam?')
['The', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'And', 'the', 'eggs', 'ham', 'and', 'spam']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby for this too

```
from itertools import groupby
x = [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(text, str.isalnum) if k]
```

eg.

```
>>> text = 'The foo bar baz! And the eggs, ham and spam?'
>>> x = [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(text, str.isalnum) if k]
>>> x
['The', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'And', 'the', 'eggs', 'ham', 'and', 'spam']
```